# How to embed a youtube video in an XML file?

Tags: xml, video, youtube, embed

I downloaded this template from templatemonster.com.  I have been editing it slowly and just recently decided I would like to put a video on it.  However, I have not been able to get it to work.  Does anyone know the actual code used in XML to embed a video?

Code Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<content>
    <!-- general vars -->
    <settings>
        <item name="copyright"><![CDATA[<font letterspacing=".3">Title here... &#169; Year here...  |  <a href="event:privacy,0">PRIVACY POLICY</a></font>]]></item>
        <item name="companyName"><![CDATA[Title here...]]></item>
        <item name="companySlogan"><![CDATA[Title here...]]></item>
        <item name="fullScreTitle"><![CDATA[<a href="event:fullScren">      </a>]]></item>

        <image imageUrl="images/tfile_logo.png"/> <!-- Logo spot! -->
        <!--page name-->

        <iconShare imageUrl="images/tfile_icon1.png" url="http://demolink.org/"/> <!--Facebook Icon-->
        <iconShare imageUrl="images/tfile_icon2.png" url="http://demolink.org/"/> <!--Twitter Icon-->
        <!-- <mp3Url srcUrl="music.mp3"/> -->


    </settings>


    <!-- menu -->
        <menu>
            <button><![CDATA[HOME]]></button>
            <button><![CDATA[ABOUT US]]></button>       
            <button><![CDATA[SERVICES]]></button>       
            <button><![CDATA[DID YOU KNOW?]]></button>      
            <button><![CDATA[TESTIMONIALS]]></button>       
            <button><![CDATA[CONTACTS]]></button>       

        </menu>

<!-- pages -->
<!-- URL images  linkURL="http://DEMOLINK.ORG/" linkPage = "1 "  - (1  - Num read More) -->

<pages>
<titlePage name="HOME"/>

<titlePage name="ABOUT US">
<imagesPage>
<image imageUrl="images/tfile_page1_pic1.jpg" />
</imagesPage>
<texts>
<pageText><![CDATA[Title here...]]></pageText>
<pageText><![CDATA[Text here...]]></pageText>
<pageText><![CDATA[Title here...]]></pageText>
<pageText><![CDATA[Text here...]]></pageText>
<pageText><![CDATA[Title here...]]></pageText>
<pageList>
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>ASHI BAR</u></b>]]></txt>
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>BBB QUALIFICATIONS</u></b>]]></txt>
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>WASHINGTON STATE REQ'S</u></b>]]></txt>              
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>ANOTHER LINK</u></b>]]></txt>                
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>ANOTHER LINK</u></b>]]></txt>                
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>ANOTHER LINK</u></b>]]></txt>                
<txt link="http://www.demolink.org"><![CDATA[<b><u>ANOTHER LINK</u></b>]]></txt>                
</pageList>
<readMoreText linkPage="0"><![CDATA[<font letterspacing="-.2"><b>Button name here...</b></font>]]></readMoreText>
<readMoreText linkPage="1"><![CDATA[<font letterspacing="-.2"><b>Button name here...</b></font>]]></readMoreText>
</texts>
<pagePopup>
<popup>
<item name="title"><![CDATA[Title here...]]></item>
<item name="linkText"><![CDATA[Text here...]]></item>
</popup>
<popup>
<item name="title"><![CDATA[Title here...]]></item>
<item name="linkText"><![CDATA[Text here...


                        I WANT TO PUT A VIDEO HERE!

                        <embed
                        width="420" height="345"
                        src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
                        type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                            </embed>]]></item>

                    </popup>
                </pagePopup>
            </titlePage>
```

Does this give enough information now?  It's from the start of the document all the way down to the point at which I'm trying to change things.

Comment: XML itself has no notion of video, so you should tell us the templating system or framework you're using in order for your question to make sense.

Comment: Hey kjhughes, I'm not sure what you mean by tempting system or framework.  Do you mean: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` ?

Comment: We need to know the program that processes the `popup`, `item`, etc XML elements before we could possibly know whether there is an element that you could use to embed a video. "I downloaded this template from templatemonster.com" is too ambiguous.

Comment: I updated it to show the code from the beginning of the file up to where we were before.  Is that what you needed?

Comment: No, you should provide the name and preferably a link to the templating system you're using.  I'll try to help with an answer below anyway, but you'd get better help if you'd be more clear in describing the templating system you're using.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey kjhughes,
  First I want to say thank you for all the help you tried to give me back in January.  I honestly had no clue what I was talking about.  While I am still learning, I have learned the function of XML and understand what you are asking me now.  The XML file is used by a shockwave flash program.  Here is the template link: http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/41114.html?utm_campaign=map&utm_medium=email&utm_source=yotpo&yotpo_token=afc9f3a21341413cf9c8e9df77a00e1804d4f857

Answer (score 2):

The `content`, `settings`, `item`, `menu`, and `button` elements shown in your code are from a templating system which you should identify to see if it also has an element for embedding videos.

Without knowing the templating system, I can offer you this insight:  `CDATA` is likely being used to pass regular HTML through to the output.  You could therefore try these two approaches:

(1) Within `CDATA`, use regular HTML to embed a video:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" 
        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

(2) Outside of `CDATA`, use whatever provisions the templating system provides.  (Deterimine this!)  Perhaps it is the `embed` tag that you were trying to work inside of `CDATA`.  If so, move it outside of any `CDATA` section.  For example:

```
<item name="linkText">
  <embed
      width="420" height="345"
      src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  </embed>
</item>
```

When you look up the documentation for your templating system for the tag to use to embed a video, you should also take note of where such tag may be placed in the template.  (Is it allowed in a `item` with `@name="linkText"`, for example?)